# Google sheet automatically calculation in other sheet upon receiving new form response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a form which records employee vacation data through google form. It has two dates start date and end date. Now I want to list all the date for the range in other sheet upon new form response and copy the form response for all those dates automatically. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will append it to the new sheet in the new spreadsheet

```
function onformsubmit(e) {
  const nss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('new spreadsheet id');
  const nsh = nss.getSheetByName('Sheet name');
  nsh.appendRow([e.namedValues['start date name'][0],e.namedValues['end date name'][0]]);
}
```

You will have to create in onformsubmit trigger for the linked spreadsheet.  You will need write access to the new spreadsheet/sheet

Run this to create trigger:

```
function createTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onformsubmit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onformsubmit").forSpreadsheet(ss).onFormSubmit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I add weekday.intl function in it to extract specific dates ?

Comment: You can format with Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MM dd, yyyy");

Comment: Namedvalues throwing an error.

Comment: can you please provide me with sample spreadsheet as it did went through but it is not doing what I asked on my end.

Comment: It `namedValues` You learn more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I used the same code you provided, it’s working but no as I asked, it list only start date , other columns are listed as [Ljava.lang.object.some number . 

I am using my company laptop for code and asking questions from my person email so it will be hard to copy and paste.  Apologies for inconvenience.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-GAcPoyv5dd94-OTBrRT43vIaROC1_ZzZ9qUSmVipcM/edit

I created a sample spreadsheet here. Consider Sheet2 as my form response. And whatever I put in Sheet 1 is the expected output.

Comment: You were not specific about what  your asking for and I don't follow links google accounts.  Be specific and post everything needed for the question in the question.